# Tool to Generate Mock XML With Filled in Values From C# Class

Tags: c#, xml, testing, mocking

Sometimes when working with legacy code I get gigantic objects I need to mock to pass through applications...objects with like 200 property's

Instead of building out the object manually is there a way I can generate a mock xml object from a C# class with the values filled in? For example:

```
public Class Animal
{
    public bool hasWings {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int numberOfFeet {get; set;}
}
```

would turn into:

```
<Animal>
  <hasWings>true</hasWings>
  <name>string</name>
  <numberOfFeet>0</numberOfFeet>
</Animal>
```

I don't need actual real values...just placeholders

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below method to get the job done. This will create an object with default fill out the values:
**Update:** Added recursive call to handle properties of class type

```
private static object GetDummyObject(Type type)
{
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    if (obj != null)
    {
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(String))
            {
                property.SetValue(obj, property.Name.ToString(), null);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                property.SetValue(obj, Array.CreateInstance(type.GetElementType(), 0), null);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                var ob = GetDummyObject(property.PropertyType);
                property.SetValue(obj, ob, null);
            }
            else
            {
                var o = GetDefault(property.PropertyType);
                property.SetValue(obj, o, null);
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
}

public static object GetDefault(Type type)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

There are some limitation. This will only generate object for default constructors but you can always extend it.

Now if you need XML then just serialize the object returned from this method.

Comment: ooo nice, what is GetDefault? VS is throwing that it wants a method there

Comment: Getmethod is just a wrapper around Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType). Replace the line and you should be good to go.

Comment: nice that works...im working on expanding on your solution making it recursive so it can drill down into large class objects and set values there...get a null reference exception if there is a sub-class right now

Comment: I have updated the code to handle nested class objects.

Comment: Nice i've tried a version of the above...for some reason I can't get past

Comment: one wrinkle is the handling of read-only attributes...its throwing the index of the iteration off

Comment: Do you mean you have readonly properties? Put a check when entering the foreach `if(!property.CanWrite) continue;`

Comment: im gonna give you credit for this one because it works with most objects which is fantastic...however it has trouble with large amount of read-onlys throwing the index off

Comment: Glad it helped!! If you can provide a sample where it's throwing exception we can tweak the solution.